# How to redirect with Session Flashed in laravel? below code is not working

Tags: php, laravel, session

Laravel Redirecting With Flashed Session Data,
How to #pass_html_tag like: 
 With Flashed Session? Below code is not working:

```
$msg = '<p>text 1 </p><br><h3>text 2 </h3><br><p>text 3</p> <br>';
```

return redirect('/subscription-success')->with('success', $msg);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass your message to your views in two ways:

first:

`return redirect('/subscription-success')->with('message', $msg);`

second:

```
Session::flash('message', '$msg');
return redirect('/subscription-success');
```

After that You should check in your view if the page have session message then show it:

```
@if(Session::has('message'))
     {!! Session::get('message') !!}
@endif
```

Comment: @nazmulhaqued you wouldn't use $msg in your view..You should use ```{{Session::get('message')}}``` in place you need in view

Comment: @nazmulhaqued $msg is a varibale you pass it to session in your controller..not to use in view

Comment: Sorry now pass the variable to the view, but html tag showing like normal text. like <p>অভিনন্দন!</p>

Comment: @nazmulhaqued yes..if your text has html tags use like this ```{!! Session::get('message') !!}```